# Split a combined pdf into its individual files

Tags: pdf, pdfsharp

I see examples where a combined pdf file can be split into multiple files, but is it possible to split a combined pdf by the names of the underlying files. For instance, combined pdf cp was created by combining files a.pdf, b.pdf and c.pdf. I want to split up the combined pdf cp back to its component files a.pdf, b.pdf, and c.pdf. I've looked at pdfsharp, but I didn't see a way to do it. Would a different utility fit the bill?

Comment: there is no standard way the names and page ranges of the original file are stored in the merged file.

Comment: That's too bad. I was hoping it would be straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you control the combining part as well (in other words, if you are generating that merged PDF yourself) then there could be a way. You could store that information, the range and the name of the original PDF files somewhere within the resulting combined PDF file.

For example, you could perhaps use bookmarks to store this information.
Something like the following:

```
private static void MergePdfs(string[] files, string outputFile)
{
    using (PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument())
    {
        foreach (string file in files)
            using (PdfDocument sourceDocument = PdfDocument.Load(file))
                foreach (PdfPage sourcePage in sourceDocument.Pages)
                {
                    PdfPage clonedPage = document.Pages.AddClone(sourcePage);
                    PdfOutline outline = document.Outlines.AddLast(Path.GetFileName(file));
                    outline.SetDestination(clonedPage, PdfDestinationViewType.FitPage);
                }

        document.Save(outputFile);
    }
}
```

You would then be able to retrieve that information.
Something like the following:

```
private static void SplitPdfs(string inputFile, string outputFolder)
{
    using (PdfDocument document = PdfDocument.Load(inputFile))
    {
        PdfOutline outline = document.Outlines.First;
        PdfDocument destination = null;
        string file = null;
        int index = 0;

        do
        {
            if (file != outline.Title)
            {
                if(destination != null)
                {
                    destination.Save(Path.Combine(outputFolder, file));
                    destination.Close();
                }

                file = outline.Title;
                destination = new PdfDocument();
            }

            destination.Pages.AddClone(document.Pages[index++]);
            outline = outline.Next;
        }
        while (outline != null);

        destination.Save(Path.Combine(outputFolder, file));
        destination.Close();
    }
}
```

Note, the code uses [GemBox.Pdf](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/pdf), you can find here the [merge](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/pdf/examples/c-sharp-vb-net-merge-pdf/201) and the [split](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/pdf/examples/c-sharp-vb-net-split-pdf/202) examples.
Last, there is probably a smarter way how you could store the necessary information, but nevertheless this should work as well and you can try it with something like the following:

```
string[] pdfs = { "Sample1.pdf", "Sample2.pdf", "Sample3.pdf" };
string resultFile = "Result.pdf";

MergePdfs(pdfs, resultFile);

string resultFolder = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(resultFile),
    Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(resultFile));
Directory.CreateDirectory(resultFolder);

SplitPdfs(resultFile, resultFolder);
```

Comment: NixonUposseen - I like your answer, but unfortunately we do not control the combining part. I will keep your solution in mind for the future if I ever need it. Thank you.